# How do I convert an existing makefile for Visual Studio back into a solution file (*.sln)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I would like to open an existing Visual Studio project in Visual Studio, so I can change some parameters. However, I only have the makefile (which I can compile without any problems with nmake). How would I convert this make file back into its original solution/project file format?

Comment: With the tool between your ears.  There's no other.  Could be easy if the make rules are simple, could be next to impossible.  Only way to find out is try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: I don't even need to do this.

The only reason I originally wanted to convert "makefile" >> "Visual Studio solution" was to create a x32 build, so I could run it on a 32-bit OS. However, since the original app was compiled for "All CPU", it worked just fine on the 32-bit OS without any problems.